# https pages in facebook app/iframe

Tags: facebook, http, iframe, canvas, https

Got this really weird problem when loading https pages into my facebook app (when the app is running as http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxx).

If i do declare wether its http or https using.

```
FB._https = (window.location.protocol === 'https:');
```

On my https pages the facebook javascript api fails silently or atleast the setSize function. When loading http pages into the iframe it works fine.

If i do not declare if its https or not i get a security warning in IE, in all other browsers it works fines.

If i set my settings to run the app as https and all my pages are in https then it works fine.

But the thing is that if a user runs facebook on http, then i must be able to display some pages as https in the iframe, anyone had any similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

Similar problem here - I put together a  [proof-of-concept](http://apps.facebook.com/autogrow-mixed-ssl/) for testing. This has been [filed as a bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/193525330729332) and is apparently being looked at. It might help if you go and +1 the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is using facebook on http and they visit your app which is set up for https, they will just see the https page. Or you can set up a http canvas page as well as your https one. You don't need to put in any of those workarounds..

Comment: cheers for the reply. but unfortunatly that is not the issue. i do got both a http and a https canvass page. the problem is that if someone is using the http canvas page on occation i then would need to load a https page (into the http canvas) thats when it fails.

Comment: Just put a https url in the http canvas page setting then

Comment: also tried that, seems like the problem is when the protocols dont match between the window.top.location and the cnavas protocol.

Comment: that is not possible since fb will fail the request if the user browse facebook non-secure.

Comment: Create a http canvas which redirects to the secure one?

Comment: might be so that the real issue is why ie give security warnings. the all.js is called by //connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js which should match both protocols, why it doesnt beats me. And setting the FB._https, might not even be the issue.

Comment: I doubt that modifying FB._https will do anything but break something. Do you have a link to the http page? Are you correctly loading the api over the matching protocol?

Comment: as said loading it by // which supports both http and https though hard setting it to https doesnt do the trick either, reckon the problem is that the outerframe is http iframe https which makes the api https and then it cant talk with the http outer fb frame causing the security warnings i ie.